# How to make dependency transitive in Gradle

Tags: maven, jakarta-mail, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gmail-api

I have downloaded javax.mail-api-1.5.3.jar file copied into app/libs folder and then right click , add as library. Then following line appears under dependency

```groovy
compile files('libs/javax.mail-api-1.5.3.jar')
```

I want to make this dependency transitive.Because I have mention javax.mail-api library dependencies in pom.xml file like follows.

```xml
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I also tried

```groovy
compile (files('libs/javax.mail-api-1.5.3.jar')){
    transitive true
}
```

then this error occurs.

```
    Error:(34, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
    Possible causes:
The project 'MeetingManager' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    Open Gradle wrapper file 

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
    Apply Gradle plugin
```

I don't no what to do next, Please help.

My build.Gradle file looks like

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.meetingmanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile (files('libs/javax.mail-api-1.5.3.jar')){
        transitive true
    }

}
```

Comment: For those who are still facing this issue. DON'T use javax.mail-api-1.5.3.jar. Go to this [link](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list), download all three jars, put it in lib folder, and add lib folder in dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.mail-api-1.5.3` can also be downloaded from existing repositories (probably jCenter or mavenCentral) described in your build file. If you aren't tied to using your downloaded version in `/libs`, you might do this in your build file:

```
dependency {
  compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
}
```

The default behavior in this case is to download transitive dependencies when you specify it like this.

Here's a reference to that repository : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.5.3

Comment: I already tried this. Gradle compiles it successfully but when I run my app and tried to send message the following error occurs. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger. So I looked for solution and I find this.                                  http://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/.                                                                                                      It says you want to edit the pom.xml file, thats why I downloaded the .jar file and edit its pom.xml file and want to add it to gradle.

Comment: First, I think you seem to be misunderstanding the point of that post.  They are telling you to add those dependencies to the pom of your project (in this case it would have been an Android project, not your build of the jar).  But since you're using gradle, just add those dependencies to your gradle build file. Just add the extra dependency yourself `compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'`

Comment: Also if you only want them in the test scope (which is what the pom.xml is specifying), use `testCompile` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Yeah you were right, I misunderstood. Now I have added these two dependencies in my gradle build file. Now I get this error  `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:` 
`com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/mail/Folder;` Any ideas why I am getting this ..??And how can I resolve it ?

Comment: You might want to post a new question for that with more details.